# How can I make up a Familiar Companion Edge?

Tags: savage-worlds, house-rules, savage-worlds-fantasy, familiars

I've been thinking about it a lot, and well... there's already the beastmaster edge out there, however it doesn't really seems fit for an arcane character, as in other systems familiars are far more complex or offer a vast array of options, rather than "just being there", which is what the Beast Master Edge does (Indeed the edge is basic at worst...).

Any GM tips, I've been tweaking no good...

Comment: What flavour are you after?  From what I see, the ability to have a loyal animal companion that could be anything including a snake, crow, mouse, owl, cat, etc. fits the "familiar" concept.  Are you more concerned about how much control you do or do not have over the beast?

Answer (score 9):

The Savage Worlds [Fantasy Companion](http://www.peginc.com/pdfstore/savage-worlds-fantasy-companion-pdf/) includes a Familiar Edge which fits the bill. If you're doing a fantasy campaign, pick that up.

Answer (score 4):

[Houserules for more D&D-style familiars in Savage Worlds](http://www.kript.net/SavageWorlds/familiars.html) have already published and look like more the sort of thing you have in mind. The gist of it is that familiars can be imbued with power points to give them more abilities. It includes two Edges, one to gain the familiar and set its initial powers, and one to improve the familiar later.

Personally, I like these rules, but I would change one thing: the loyalty clause in the Familiar Edge would get deleted at my table. Abuse your familiar all you want, and it remains bound to obey and serve you! Nothing like a familiar who hates you as a juicy bit of plot, as they seek to ultimately betray you while keeping true to the letter of your commands. ;)

Comment: I like how it seems... however I find it quite unbalanced as the familiar gets it as a natural ability more than a power. So you could transfer all of your PP to your familiar and let him blast thru armies with infinite PP, if you get lucy and get him Armor +4 with an animal with 8 toughness... things could get pretty ugly... AND if it dies you lose your PP forever. That's where the balance is supposed to be but... maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: If you transfer all your power points, you've got nothing left for spells. Even losing a few PP permanently is a pretty big sacrifice. Seems OK to me.

Comment: Your last paragraph smells rather of brimstone and *impish* to me.